# Regular expression lowercase letter followed by a number

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the hang of regular expression. I'm scanning through an xml file and I want to do is find any word starting with a lowercase letter fallowed by a number e.g. `c1234`I assume it's something like `[a-z 0-9]` but it's finding single characters instead of a whole word. Any ideas on how to do this would really be appreciated.

Comment: `\b[a-z]\d+\b` would work i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-z]\d+` will work just fine.

It looks for any lowercase letter followed by any amount of digits.

Comment: you're a time saver. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

About regex you can read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

test your regex you can here: http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

I think, you help this construction: `\b[a-z]\d+`